# How to implement static tradingview chart

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

For strategy executing history I have to implement TV chart with defined range which is not changed on scroll. The main issue is with `getBars` method, which provides `periodParams` object with from, to and countBack and it changes depends on user's scroll. How can I set from/to manual?

```
      const { isStrategyChart, range: { end = null, start = null, candleSeed = null } } = this.props
      const {
        from, to, firstDataRequest, countBack,
      } = periodParams
      let startDate = from
      let endDate = to

      if (isStrategyChart && candleSeed) {
        startDate = start / 1000 - candleSeed * 60

        if (end) {
          endDate = end / 1000
        }
      }

     // fetching logic
```

`range` is the object with execution range params. And all fetched and visible candles should be limited by this range (including candle seed time)